# Abstract algebra: ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $$R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$$
>   $I = (3, 2 + \sqrt{-5})$ is an ideal of $R$.

Show that $R/(3)$ has $9$ elements and $I/(3)$ has $3$ elements.

I have tried $(3) = \lbrace 3a + 3b\sqrt{-5} \rbrace$, but I can only guess some elements in $R/(3)$. How shall I prove that there are exactly 9 elements in $R/(3)$?

Comment: What is $I$ in $I/(3)$?

Comment: You should write out the problem more clearly and lay out what you have tried to do to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The first part follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)$$
So $R∕(3)\cong\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2-1)\cong\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ which has $9$ elements.

Comment: Should it be 9 elements?

Comment: @Delong Oops, thank you!